# C++ encode/compress/condense string containing comma separated numbers, how?

Tags: c++, compression

I have a string containing comma separated numbers (they're float, but I can convert to int). I want to send this string as data in a cURL POST request, but unfortunately sometimes the string can be too long to be sent so my program crashes. For this reason I want to condense the string into a shorter form before sending it. The fact that it is using char bytes to only store numbers from 0-9 plus commas plus (maybe) a decimal mark makes it fertile ground for compression, right?

I thought of writing something that would do the job but then decided to search for some libraries. I tried using zlib but couldn't crack it, same with a couple others, but I'm starting to think my task isn't complicated enough to use these advanced libraries, especially since I want the data to be in string format (not binary) so I can include it in a URL header. Surely there can be an easy way of doing this, no?

Here is my input sample:

"1, 2, 4, 2, 3.421, 3, 4.54, 3.43"

But for thousands of numbers.

I was thinking something along the lines of combining each couple of consecutive numbers by encoding them in one char.

Comment: Lets say a number within 20 decimal places is 20 characters (20 odd bytes). You can fit 500 numbers in 1K. Where is the problem? BTW - Fix your program.

Comment: How about base64 encoding?

Comment: Ed, my data is an array of hundreds of floats.

Comment: Lets say 500 floats, 20 characters a piece. 500 x 20 = 10000 chars = `10 k = 10 IP packets = Nothing.

Comment: I consistently get crashes when the string size exceeds a certain length (definitely shorter than 10000 chars). I'm using cURL library in Cocos2d-x.

Comment: What Ed is saying is that if you're using POST you should be posting this data as part of the body and that you'll unlikely run in to problems here unless the server is limiting the upload.  I suspect you're actually putting these values directly in the URL (the query string), and that's why you're hitting this limit.

Comment: Hmmm, thanks for the help, everyone :)
Let me test it and get back to you. Give me five minutes.
But even if I resolve the crash, it would still be a good idea to compress the data, wouldn't it?

Comment: @user1235155 - Avoid premature optimizations.  Consider compression only if you really need it; when you have to debug things at a later date, you'll be thankful.

Comment: Alright, seems I underestimated the number of chars, which can reach more than 100,000 chars. There was some sort of limit I was oblivious to, and I can increase it a bit but I still feel I should try condensing each couple of numbers into one char. Going to try to do that.

Comment: Compressing only delays the problem.  Someone will send you input that doesn't fit even with compression.